# How to pass an array to a jenkins parameterized job via remote access api?

Tags: json, curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to call a Jenkins parameterized job using curl command. I am following [Remote API Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).

I have Active choice parameter plugin. One of the parameters of the job is an Active choice reactive parameter.

Here is the screenshot of the job:

[image]

I am using the following curl command to trigger it with parameter:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/active-choice-test/buildWithParameters -u abhishek:token --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"state", "value":"Maharashtra"},{"name":"cities", "value":["Mumbai", "Pune"]}]}'
```

But I am not able to pass the cities parameter which should be a json array. The above script is giving error.

I am printing the state & cities variable like this:

[image]

The job is getting executed and showing error for cities:

```
Started by user abhishek
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/active-choice-test
[active-choice-test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson499503098295318443.sh
+ echo Maharashtra
Maharashtra
+ echo error
error
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Please tell me how to pass array parameter to a jenkins parameterized job while using remote access API?

Answer (score -2):

You may change the value to strings rather than array:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/active-choice-test/buildWithParameters -u abhishek:token --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"state", "value":"Maharashtra"},{"name":"cities", "value":"Mumbai,Pune"}]}'`